# Synchronously load and evaluate a dynamically generated script in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to synchronously load and evaluate a script from a third-party. This works fine:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This prints 'exists' as expected
    console.log(typeof jQuery === "function" ? 'exists' : 'not yet');
  </script>
</head>
```

But, how would you do this if the `src` URL is dynamically built and can't be hard-coded? This doesn't work:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Build the URL here
    const src = 'https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.js';
    // Create the script tag
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', src);
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This prints 'not yet'
    console.log(typeof jQuery === "function" ? 'exists' : 'not yet');
  </script>
</head>
```

I guess, `document.write` could do the trick. But, [this seems like a bad idea.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write)

What would you recommend?

---

In my real use case, I need to load the [`utag.sync.js`](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/Using-the-utag-sync-js-Script/ta-p/19175#toc-hId-1329434506) script:

```html
<script src="https://tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/[account]/[profile]/[env]/utag.sync.js"></script>
```

`env` is the dynamic part that is determined based on `location.hostname`.

Comment: It won't work because it takes time to load the script, and by then your console already have a `"not yet"`. Give it a callback and do `s.onload = callback`.

Comment: what part of `const src = 'https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.js';` is the dynamically built one? What's the actual problem? What are you trying to build?

Comment: @Thomas See the updated question.

Comment: To me, this feels like it's supposed to be done in the backend. At least I'd build that url in the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script load is asynchronous because of the time it takes to download the remote file. So, if you want to know if your script has finished loading, you can attach a "load" event listener on your script element (`s` in your example).

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Build the URL here
    const src = 'https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.js';
    // Create the script tag
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // This prints 'exists'
      console.log(typeof jQuery === "function" ? 'exists' : 'not yet');
    });
    s.setAttribute('src', src);
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This prints 'not yet'
    console.log(typeof jQuery === "function" ? 'exists' : 'not yet');
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Things are better with a snippet.

Comment: In my real use case, I want to make sure that the body is rendered **after** the script finished loading. This is the official recommendation: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/iQ-Tag-Management/Using-the-utag-sync-js-Script/ta-p/19175#toc-hId-1329434506

Comment: The doc assumes you load your script directly, not via javascript. In your example you could either build the src url dynamically on your server, or hide the page until the script has finished loading.

Comment: Yeah, building it on the server makes the most sense. Thanks!